# Butter knife is not working in my existing project after using another project as a library in android

Tags: android, module, butterknife

`compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'`

```
@BindView(R.id.tvName)
TextView tvName;
private Unbinder unbinder;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_view, container, false);

unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
tvName.setText(name);    //its throwing null pointer exception
}
```

if I remove the library from my project then butterknife is working perfectly.

Comment: What library did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after adding an empty library module to a project, ButterKnife stopped working and it reported an error on all **@BindView** annotation usages.

```
Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element
public abstract int butterknife.BindView.value() (Found data of type R.id)
```

The issue turned out to be that the package name of the library module was the same as the one of the app module. After changing the package name, the errors went away.